# AngularJS - TypeError: v2.[xxxx] is not a function

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to conditionally set the background position of a div element based on their array index using ng-style. Each div is being generated using ng repeat.

In my html page, I have the following code snippet:

```
    <div style="position:absolute; z-index:1; width:100px; height:100px" ng-style="navigationStyleToilet(o)" ng-repeat="o in arr"></div>
```

In my controller.js, I have the following code snippet:

```
  $scope.navigationStyleToilet = [];
  $scope.arr = [];
  // get data from service.js
  var categoryInfo = NavigationService.fnGetCategoryInfo(strCategoryName);

   for (i = 0; i < categoryInfo.length; i++)
    {
        $scope.arr.push(i);
        var targetImageX = categoryInfo[i].X;
        var targetImageY = categoryInfo[i].Y;
        $scope.navigationStyleToilet[i] = {
          "background-position": targetImageX + " " + targetImageY
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, it gives me the error that says "TypeError: v2.navigationStyleToilet is not a function".

I have tried a couple different things, however I cant conditionally set the background position of the div element based on their array index using ng-style. Does anyone know a way I could make this work? Thanks.

Comment: do you have values inside $scope.navigationStyleToilet?

Comment: Values? Basically, $scope.navigationStyleToilet is a ng-style of a div. The div will be generated repeatedly and I want to conditionally set different background position for each div, based on its array index. Btw, I have updated my question as I forgot to mention that I have declared and instantiate   $scope.navigationStyleToilet = [];

Comment: Below answer is as per updated question !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get element from array, you should use indexer in the array. So, your indexer in ng-style should be

```
ng-style="navigationStyleToilet[o]"
```

Your code `ng-style="navigationStyleToilet(o)"` would assume it as function and call in that way. So, you should user indexer instead of calling the function.
Make sure, o should indexing value to get data from array.

You can use $index if you want to get index what ng-repeat produce. So, your code might be like this :

```
ng-style="navigationStyleToilet[$index]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You dont need a seprate function for this.

you can put ng-repeat on categoryInfo by changing it to:

```
$scope.categoryInfo
```

and

```
 <div style="position:absolute; z-index:1; width:100px; height:100px" ng-style="{'background-position': o.X + 'px ' + o.Y +'px' }" ng-repeat="o in categoryInfo">{{o}}</div>
```

Solved here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Nh0Kp0zI77JIxcApTYSQ?p=preview

You might be missing **px or %** in the values as they are required in 'background-position' property

But as you can see (by inspecting element) in above plunkr both the div have 'background-position' then also they are overlapsing:

So you might be looking for something like this:

```
ng-style="{'left': o.X + 'px ', 'top': o.Y +'px' }" ng-repeat="o in categoryInfo"
```

See here: https://plnkr.co/edit/g0h7IsG1kSkNQmSLBDWY?p=preview

Hope This helps. :)